# Is it possible to add the whole folder of openzeppelin-contracts to Remix IDE?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

I can't find the option to add the whole folder, only seperate files.

Is it possible to add the whole folder of openzeppelin-contracts to Remix IDE?

Also, what is the correct link to import the whole folder from github?

Comment: Why do you need whole folder? Add min dependencies not all, unused contracts from  3'rd part lib

Comment: Well your right, and actually thats how i solved it. But still it's weird to me that there is no option to add the whole folder or I am just uknown of that

Comment: Because when you add never used contracts to your project codebase, like whole folder from external project/lib, you are polluting your codebase. And that's action is usually unwanted and not a good practice.

Comment: @kj-crypto if you add a lot of code that doesn't mean you are going to deploy all that

Comment: I have ~10 contracts, it'd really help if I could just upload the entire contracts folder (as all contracts are used), instead of manually importing each of them.